# Your license for Microsoft Search Server has expired

Tags: 2007, search

When I queried for search in MOSS 2007 portal, I encountered an exception that states : "Your license for Microsoft Search Server has expired"

Microsoft Search Server 2008 Express Trial was installed in MOSS production server. Now Microsoft Search Server 2008 Express is free to download and use, **but I am confused what does "Express Trial" means**.

In SharePoint Central Admin 3.0 I found this:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar experience previously and if I remember, it was resolved using the hotfix - [KB971620](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971620) - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971620

It happens due to an installation of SP2 for MOSS servers. This incorrectly triggers the expiry date for some office products installed (Check the "Applies To" section of the article) and displays the message - "Trial Version Has Expired"

Follow the instructions after installing the hotfix and it should work. Good Luck.